# SharePoint 2007 filtered list does not expand in IE11

Tags: 2007

Hi can someone help why some IE11 users does not seems to be able to expand the Filtered Group By lists ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Permanent Fix:** Install the Hot fix!

[A hotfix is available for the ASP.NET browser definition files in the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and in the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100/en-us)

We can also force Internet explorer 10 to work on IE9 compatibility mode by setting the META tag in SharePoint Master page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

**Temporary Fix:** Set the Browser Mode to IE 8!

How? Press F12, which fires IE Developer Tools. Select "Browser Mode: IE8". You can also try setting User Agent string to IE 8 from tools menu of IE Development tools.